# c3js convert xAxis count from decimal to Integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I have a custom xAxis like this in my c3 chart which contain some customize value, but the xAxis's count value got some decimal at the moment, how may i convert it to Integer?

```
  axis: {
         x: {
            label: {
                text: 'Title',
                position: 'outer-center',
                },                  
                    tick: {
                    count:17, 
                        }
                    }
            },
```

JSfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/113/

Answer (score 0):

seem i solve my own question again... we can use javascript  Math.ceil()

```
format: function (d) { return Math.ceil(d); }
```